# nuger.server's FindPackagesById() is not returning pre-release packages

Tags: nuget, nuget-server

I am trying to query the nuget server using the FindPackagesById() web method. But it is not returning the pre-release versions of the package. I am sure that there's a way to do it. Any help would be appreciated. ;0)

**The example below is how I am running the search**

```
http://localhost/nuget/FindPackagesById()?id='NugetTestApp1'
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem was that in order for the FindPackagesById() to return pre-release packages we must set the semVerLevel to 2.0.0.

```
http://localhost/nuget/FindPackagesById()?id='NugetTestApp1'&semVerLevel=2.0.0
```

Answer (score 0):

The V2 protocol is not very well documented (the V3 protocol is for [example](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/api/overview)), and that's what the NuGet.Server supports.

However, there is an unofficial [docs](https://joelverhagen.github.io/NuGetUndocs) effort for V2.

Now the support for FindPackagesById may differ from implementation to implementation (for example, NuGet.org does not support the filters).
I'd suggest using the packages endpoint as it's a standard OData collection so it's easier to write queries against it.

Example

`http://localhost/nuget/Packages()?$filter=Id%20eq%20%27nuget.protocol%27%20and%20IsPrerelease%20eq%20true&$select=Id,Version`

Comment: I tried running the query that you provided, but it is still not returning any pre-release packages.

Comment: The query I provide had IsPrerelease=false. 

My bad I've fixed it. Can you try again.